Guy will inherit millions only if he finds a wife
There is this Hollywood movie from the 90's in which the guy (Casanova type) inherits millions from his dad or grand father's will but the will comes with a catch, to inherit the property he must get married.
I don't remember the whole movie but he goes all over the country to ask forgiveness from all the women he has slept with, eventually falling in love with some lawyer (chick) who is looking over the will condition.
Like I said I don't remember the whole movie. I want to see it again but can't recall its name or the actor. 
Can you people help me out here? I saw that movie in HBO (if it helps). I'm sure it's comedy romance

It's a remake of Brewster's Millions with a twist. The star actor is a famous comedian of this era. It's at the tip of my tongue but can't find it. I could think of Terence Hill, but he is 70's. I can see him in the A-team i think. I'm looking for that movie too because i lost my vcr copy.

OK, perhaps you're referring to Bad Boy (AKA Dawg) from 2002 with Denis Leary and Elizabeth Hurley. From Wiki:

Douglas "Dawg" Munford (Denis Leary) is the ultimate womanizer: He is selfish, rude and totally uncaring about what a woman thinks after they have sex. He arrives too late for his grandmother's funeral but, no matter, she has left him a cool million subject to one condition.
As explained by estate executor Anna Lockhart (Elizabeth Hurley), Douglas must contact at least a dozen of the scores of women he has seduced and left during his lifetime and beg for their forgiveness. Reluctantly, Dawg sets out on his odyssey which takes him, and the lawyer, to venues throughout California. Later, he falls for Anna. 

Sorry about that. Here's the trailer:




FINALLY THE ONE I WAS LOOKING FOR!! You are awesome!!

We got there eventually. ;) Glad you found it.

Maybe The Bachelor from 1999 with Chris O'Donnell and Renée Zellweger? From IMDb:

Jimmie is seeing his single friends get married one by one. He isn't too worried until his girlfriend Anne catches the bouquet at his friend Marco's wedding. Suddenly, his wild mustang days are numbered. He finally decides to propose to her, but he sticks his foot in his mouth and botches the proposal. Being insulted by the defeatist proposal, Anne leaves town on an assignment. After she's gone, he finds out that his recently-deceased grandfather's will stipulates that he gets nothing of a multi-million dollar fortune unless he's married by 6:05pm on his 30th birthday: tomorrow! Not being able to find Anne, Jimmie begins backtracking through his past girlfriends to find a wife.

Here's the trailer:




Exactly what I thought opf as I was reading...

Actually I first thought of this but the date didn't fit. ;)

I've only ever seen the trailer for this movie and it's exactly what I thought of. Man, that must be one good trailer. Plus it's about the only other notable film O'Donnell has been in other than his two Batman films.

@Walt thanks for your help but this isn't the one I'm looking for - That guy in the movie goes all over the country to ask for forgiveness from his past girlfriend and he travels with that lawyer(girl) everywhere

@Abhilash Thanks, that helps. I have a better match and will post it right away.
